# ODBC link to Excel file stored on a website?

Tags: excel, odbc, excel-2007

I'd like to use ODBC to link from one Excel (2007 version) spreadsheet to another, where both of them are stored on a website (an Intranet website using Sharepoint). Is this possible?

When I use the Excel ODBC wizard, it expects the Excel spreadsheet to be on a local drive, and doesn't let me supply a URL as the source. (just gives the message "Couldn't read file")

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Intranet location a WebDAV location?

(I believe Sharepoint is also a WebDAV server)

If so, Windows can mount WebDav locations as a local drive...

Perhaps the Excel ODBC driver can then use that?

Comment: Thanks, that's a good suggestion. But would that not mean every user editing the linked spreadsheet has to have the Sharepoint server mounted on their local machine?